# Need the solution of Problems of Vasc and Arqady

Tags: inequality

On the [**Art of Problem Solving**](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/viewtopic.php?f=764&t=385236&p=2138741&hilit=Vasc+%26+arqady#p2138741) web site, there is a PDF file (Problems Proposed by Vasc and Arqady - Edited by Sayan Mukherjee.pdf) containing 100 problems dealing with solving inequalities.

I know it 's helpful for us to study inequalities.

I can't find the solutions to these problems. Does anyone have solutions?

Comment: You could try asking the authors. Additionally, for strategies on solving such problems, you could look at the book **Problem-Solving Strategies, CH 7, Inequalities** by Arthur Engel.

Comment: It would be helpful if you would include your question in the body of your ... question.

Comment: Perhaps it would be helpful for you to ask about individual questions you are having difficulty with. It's unreasonable to ask for someone to write up 100 solutions for you.